# Draw Box-Plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to plot this kind of chart with matplotlib?

[image: Plot]

Comment: Take a look at `pyplot.boxplot()`

Comment: This is called a boxplot, or often a "box and whisker plot".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks a lot like a boxplot to me. I created a simple figure because colleagues often ask me about it when I am presenting my data like this

[image]

If this is what you are looking for, the example code would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [-0.46,-1.25,-2.62,0.22]
x2 = [0.24,1.88,-0.49,-0.73,-0.49]
x3 = [-0.44,0.93,0.19,-4.36,-0.88]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.boxplot([x for x in [x1, x2, x3]], 0, 'rs', 1)
plt.xticks([y+1 for y in range(len([x1, x2, x3]))], ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
plt.xlabel('measurement x')
t = plt.title('Box plot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have it as an IPython notebook here: https://github.com/rasbt/matplotlib-gallery