# Plotting averages of box plots as a box plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a set of lists (about 100) of the form `[6, 17, 5, 1, 4, 7, 14, 19, 0, 10]` and I want to get one box plot which plots the averages of box-plot information (i.e. median, max, min, Q1, Q3, outliers) of all of the lists.

For example, if I have 2 lists

```
l1 = [6, 17, 5, 1, 4, 7, 14, 19, 0, 10]
l2 = [4, 12, 3, 5, 16, 0, 14, 7, 8, 15]
```

I can get averages of max, median, and min of the lists as follows:

```
maxs = np.array([])
mins = np.array([])
medians = np.array([])
for l in [l1, l2]:
    medians = np.append(medians, np.median(l))
    maxs = np.append(maxs, np.max(l))
    mins = np.append(mins, np.min(l))
averMax = np.mean(maxs)
averMin = np.mean(mins)
averMedian = np.mean(medians)
```

I should do the same for other info in the box plot such as average Q1, average Q3. I then need to use this information (averMax, averMin, etc.) to plot just one single box plot (not multiple box plots in one graph).

I know from [Draw Box-Plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337726/draw-box-plot-with-matplotlib) that you don't have to calculate the values for a normal box plot. You just need to specify the data as a variable.
Is it possible to do the same for my case instead of manually calculating the averages of the values of all the lists?

Answer (score 0):

`pd.describe()` will get the quartiles, so you can make a graph based on them. I customized the calculated numbers with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337726/draw-box-plot-with-matplotlib) and the example graph from the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

l1 = [6, 17, 5, 1, 4, 7, 14, 19, 0, 10]
l2 = [4, 12, 3, 5, 16, 0, 14, 7, 8, 15]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l1':l1, 'l2':l2}, index=np.arange(len(l1)))

df.describe()
l1  l2
count   10.000000   10.000000
mean    8.300000    8.400000
std 6.532823    5.561774
min 0.000000    0.000000
25% 4.250000    4.250000
50% 6.500000    7.500000
75% 13.000000   13.500000
max 19.000000   16.000000

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# spread,center, filer_high, flier_low
x1 = [l1[4]-1.5*(l1[6]-l1[4]), l1[4], l1[5], l1[5]+1.5*(l1[6]-l1[4])]
x2 = [l2[4]-1.5*(l2[6]-l2[4]), l2[4], l2[5], l2[5]+1.5*(l2[6]-l2[4])]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.boxplot([x for x in [x1, x2]], 0, 'rs', 1)
plt.xticks([y+1 for y in range(len([x1, x2]))], ['x1', 'x2'])
plt.xlabel('measurement x')
t = plt.title('Box plot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how do you have negative whiskers when none of the values in `l1` or `l2` are negative?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I was hoping to get one single box plot. So for example, the max in that single box plot would be **(19 + 16)/2=17.5** which the average of maxes of the lists. I have 100 of such lists and I cannot consider the box plots of all of them. I just need one box plot which would average all of them.

Comment: I didn't understand the intent of your question. If you have a large number of lists, I think you can combine them with `np.concatenate()` and then `np.percentile()`.

Comment: My intent is one box plot in a graph that shows the average data of all 100 lists. Each list is like a trial. I want to get an average of all trials in a box plot. I cannot concatenate them because each index has a specific data item.

Comment: Your question and my answer are so far apart that I should delete it? That will give you the opportunity to get an answer other than mine. If you need to delete it, please ask me.